# how access a sequence of integer

Tags: c++

I wrote this code and I wanna access the i-th element in the sequence, how to do so?

```
unsigned int power_helper( unsigned i)
{
    std::integer_sequence a = std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned, 2500>() ;

}
```

thank you

Comment: The given answer answers your question, but what problem are you *actually* trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard:

```
template <typename T, T ...I>
constexpr T IntegerSequenceAt(std::integer_sequence<T, I...>, std::size_t index)
{
    return std::array<T, sizeof...(I)>{I...}[index];
}

int main()
{
    // Prints 1.
    std::cout << IntegerSequenceAt(std::make_index_sequence<3>(), 1) << '\n';
}
```

But I have a feeling that you don't need an `integer_sequence` here. First, in a sequence returned by `make_integer_sequence`, i-th element is equal to i. And `2500` is *a lot* of elements for a parameter pack.